# Solving a recursion using its generating function

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

> Solving a recursion using its generating function
> In particular, I'm want to solve $a_{n+2}=11a_{n+1}-28a_n$ where $a_0=3$ and $a_1=0$.

The generating function for the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2$ is:$$G(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots =\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

I now have to substitute $a_n$ by $\frac{11}{28}a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{28}a_{n+2}$ and use index shifts to substitute it by $G(x)$ again. I get that:$$G(x)=\frac{-840x}{784x^2-308x+1}$$ Can someone confirm? And how should I continue to solve it for $a_n$?

Comment: This can't be your generating function because $a_0 = G(0) = 0$, and you want $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ...\\
11xG =  0 + 11a_0x + 11a_1x^2 + ...\\
28x^2G  =  0 + 0 x + 28a_0x^2 + 28a_1x^3 + ...\\
11xG-28x^2G = 11a_0x + G - a_0 - a_1x\\
11xG-28x^2G = G + 3(11x - 1)\\
G = \frac{-3(11x - 1)}{28x^2-11x+1}$